# ¿Por qué no me toma el valor de una variable?

Tags: javascript

Actualmente estoy tratando de crear un juego del tipo "ahorcado" y me he encontrado con un problema.

Cree una función en la cual compruebo si una palabra dada contiene una letra presionada, si esta no la contiene, una variable llamada "puntos" sumara 1 y según la cantidad, en un cavas, me dibujara una línea.

En otra función, igualo la variable puntos a 0, para cuando presione un botón, llame a la función y me la "reinicie" y volver a jugar.

El problema viene acá, una vez que reinicio y la letra presionada no coincide, se dibujan líneas que no coinciden con el número de la variable.

Por ejemplo, cuando la variable tenga que estar en 5 me tendría que dibujar un círculo pero cuando reinicio, al errar la primera letra, me dibuja ese círculo.

Intenté ver en la consola la variable puntos y al reiniciar, me sale dos mensajes con la misma y si reinicio de nuevo, me suma otro mensaje más pero con el valor en 1.

```js
let pantalla = document.getElementById("canvas");
let lapiz = pantalla.getContext("2d");
let palabra = 'aleatoria';
let puntos = 0;

window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event){
    if(!palabra.includes(event.key)) {
        puntos++
        console.log(puntos);
        switch (puntos) {
            case 1:
                lapiz.moveTo(500, 400);
                lapiz.lineTo(100, 400);
                lapiz.stroke();
                break;
            case 2:
                lapiz.moveTo(220, 400);
                lapiz.lineTo(220, 100);
                lapiz.stroke();
                break;
            case 3:
                lapiz.moveTo(220, 100);
                lapiz.lineTo(400, 100);
                lapiz.stroke();
                break;
            case 4:
                lapiz.moveTo(400, 100);
                lapiz.lineTo(400, 150);
                lapiz.stroke();
                break;
            case 5:
                lapiz.beginPath();
                lapiz.arc(400, 180, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                lapiz.stroke();   
                break;
        }
    }
})

function reiniciar() {
    puntos = 0;
    lapiz.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
}
document.querySelector('#reiniciar').onclick = reiniciar;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor-juego">
        <canvas height="600" width="600" id="canvas"></canvas>
        <button id="jugar">Empezar</button>
        <button id="reiniciar">Reiniciar</button>
    </div>
    <script src="/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta agregar beginPath() en tu función reiniciar

```
function reiniciar() {
    puntos = 0;
    lapiz.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    lapiz.beginPath();
}
```

Si te fijas en https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect

(Traducción):

> Nota: Tenga en cuenta que puede causar efectos secundarios no deseados si no está utilizando las vías correctamente. Asegúrese de llamar a beginPath() antes de comenzar a dibujar nuevos elementos después de llamar a  clearRect()

Comment: Ahora funciona! Muchas gracias, voy a empezar a prestar más atención a la documentación, no creía que el problema estaría en el mismo canvas.

Comment: No te preocupes la mayoría pasamos de la documentación